# Extract email:password

Tags: powershell

I'm curious if there's a way to extract `email:password` from a big list.
It is listed in the text in that format but with a few other unuseable parts in front (such as name, last name).

The format is mostly:

```
xx:Mxx:Support:xx:support@xx.com:x19000
```

But sometimes can be like this as well:

```
xxxx::gexrge@xxnt.com:111111
```

I have tried with EmEditor and if I search for

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\]).*$
```

it does find it. I have then to replace with `\1` - however this takes literally ages and finally crashes (the file is 17GB).

Knowing that powershell could do this too, I'm looking for the right command.

Comment: Import-csv or -split or convert-fromstring might work here depending on how the data is laid out. You'd need to post some of the text file with dummy data if you'd like somebody to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement allows combining efficient line-by-line processing of files (via the `-File` parameter), optionally combined with regex-matching (via the `-Regex` option):

```
& { 
  switch -regex -file in.txt { 
   '(?<=:)[^@:]+@[^:]+:.*' { $Matches[0] } 
  }
} | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 out.txt
```

<sup>Adjust the `-Encoding` argument as needed; note that in *Windows PowerShell* `utf8` creates a file *with BOM*, whereas *PowerShell [Core] v6+* creates one *wihout* BOM. By default, `Set-Encoding` uses the system's active ANSI code page in *Windows PowerShell*, whereas *PowerShell [Core] v6+* consistently defaults to BOM-less UTF-8, across all cmdlets.</sup>

The above extracts the email-password pairs extracted from file `in.txt` as individual lines to file `out.txt`.

**Note**: Even though the above performs line-by-line processing, an out-of-memory exception can apparently still occur in `Set-Content` with very large input files; the .NET-based solution in the next section should fix that, while also significantly speeding up the operation.

---

**Performance caveat**: While the above is memory-efficient, it will be slow with large files; to address that, you must make direct use of the .NET framework, via a [`System.IO.StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamWriter) instance:

```
# Create the output file.
# Note:
#  * Be sure to use a *full* path, because .NET's current dir. usually differs
#    from PowerShell's
#  * UTF-8 *without a BOM* is used as the character encoding by default,
#    but you may pass a [System.Text.Encoding] instance as needed.
$sw = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("$PWD/out.txt")

switch -regex -file in.txt { 
   '(?<=:)[^@:]+@[^:]+:.*' { $sw.WriteLine($Matches[0]) } 
}

$sw.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell function required is a split and array indexing
Here is the code you need

```
$String = "xx:Mxx:Support:xx:support@xx.com:x19000 xx:Jeremy:xxx:1977-07-22:xxx@gmail.com:bar_baz xxx:Yuxxya:xx:1975-03-28:liz@gdddaxxt.com:loddta999"
$first_seperator = ":"
$sec_seperator = " "

Function seperate ($string,$seperator){
$string.Split($seperator)
}

$mails = seperate $String $sec_seperator
foreach ($String in $mails){$mail = seperate $String $first_seperator
Write-host "The compelete mail info is " $String -f Green
Write-host "The mail is:- " $mail[4]
Write-Host "The password is :-" $mail[5]
}
```

and The output is as follows:

```
The compelete mail ifo is  xx:Mxx:Support:xx:support@xx.com:x19000
The mail is:-  support@xx.com
The password is :- x19000
The compelete mail ifo is  xx:Jeremy:xxx:1977-07-22:xxx@gmail.com:bar_baz
The mail is:-  xxx@gmail.com
The password is :- bar_baz
The compelete mail ifo is  xxx:Yuxxya:xx:1975-03-28:liz@gdddaxxt.com:loddta999
The mail is:-  liz@gdddaxxt.com
The password is :- loddta999
```

I hope that answers your question
feel free to ask for any illustration and mark this as answer if it help

Comment: Hi Mohamed, thank you! Now is there  a possibililty to just parse the email:password to output.txt as example? Just in "email:password" format? Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can add this line in the for loop:   $Requiredformat  = $mail[4]+":"+$mail[5] | out-file -Append -FilePath "c:\output.txt" -force