# Powershell: specify email:password with random data in between

Tags: powershell

Similar like this - [Extract email:password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65448263/extract-emailpassword)

However we have here the situation that in some files there is other data between the data I want to parse, as example:

email:lastname:firstname:password or email:lastname:firstname:dob:password

So my question is - with which command would I be able to ignore 2 segments like "lastname:firstname" or even 3 parts "lastname:firstname:dob". I am using the below regex to retrieve email:password from a big list.

```
$sw = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("$PWD/out.txt")

switch -regex -file in.txt { 
   '(?<=:)[^@:]+@[^:]+:.*' { $sw.WriteLine($Matches[0]) } 
}

$sw.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refine your regex:

```
# Create sample input file
@'
...:foo@example.org:password1
...:bar@example.org:lastname:firstname:password2
...:baz@example.org:lastname:firstname:dob:password3
'@ > in.txt

# Process the file line by line.
switch -regex -file in.txt { 
  '(?<=:)([^@:]+@[^:]+)(?:.*):(.*)' { '{0}:{1}' -f $Matches[1], $Matches[2] } 
}
```

For brevity, saving the output to a file was omitted above, so the email-password pairs extracted print to the screen by default, namely as:

```
foo@example.org:password1
bar@example.org:password2
baz@example.org:password3
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `(?<=:)` is a positive lookbehind assertion for ensuring that matching starts right after a `:` character.

  - Note: I based this requirement on [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65448263/extract-emailpassword) and its sample data.
- `([^@:]+@[^:]+)` uses a capture group (capturing subexpression, `(...)`) to match an email address up to but not including the next `:`.
- `(?:.*):` uses a non-capturing subexpression (`(?:...)`) that matches zero or more characters (`.*`) unconditionally followed by a `:`
- `(.*)` uses a capture group to capture all remaining characters after what is effectively the *last* `:` on each line, assumed to be the password.
- `$Matches[1]` and `$Matches[2]` refer to the 1st and 2nd capture-group matches, i.e. the email address and the password.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had data like this:

```
"lastname:firstname" 
"lastname:firstname:dob"
"lastname:firstname:password:somepassword" 
"lastname:john:firstname:jacob:password:dingleheimershmit
```

You can move through each row like this:

```
$items = gc .\stack.txt

ForEach($item in $items){

}
```

Then we can split each row on a `:` character and check each of those to see if its a match for the string `passwrod`.  If it is, then we check the next token in the row which should be a password.

This code will get you going, you'll just need to do something meaningful with `$password`.

```
$items = gc .\stack.txt

ForEach($item in $items){
    "processing $item"
    $tokens = $item.Split(":")
    For($x=0; $x -lt $tokens.Count;$x++){
        $token = $tokens[$x]
        
        #"Checking if $token is like password"
        if ($token -match "password"){
            "since this token is like password, checking next token which should be a password"
            $password = $tokens[$x+1]
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $password
        }            
    
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi foxdeploy - thank you for the input, however its not the case like this its a data base so it would be rather myusername:myemail:myfirstname:mylastname:mypassword or another file could be myemail:registrationdate:mypassword  . The thing is that the script/command I had put above was filtering email + the next string, which was then the password itself. Now however I'm dealing with files where as there is other information between email & the password . Hope thats clearly written lol, if not let me know ^^

Comment: Its more like how to parse from a file with information like 1:2:3:4, how do i get 1:3 in the output file or 2:4 , that it parses selective

Comment: Is the password always the last field?  If not, how do you know which field is the password?  If there isn't a standard data format, this would become a manual parse job.

Comment: hey Fox, its not always, so my idea was to find out with this command, how to skip a given amount of fields, lets say.Does that make sense the explanation?